# How to deserialize nested class with Gson in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

I have json as in below, I'm really new on kotlin and i tried all examples but cannot set my nested class values when i convert to json

Here my json

```
{"Init":{"MOP":[{"Id":"1","Type":"0","ProtocolVersion":"1.0","MopCode":"*NEXB","TerminalId":"'P400Plus-275008565'","IP":"'192.168.1.15'","Currency":"EUR"},{"Id":"2","Type":"0","ProtocolVersion":"1.0","MopCode":"*NEXF","TerminalId":"'P400Plus-275008565'","IP":"'10.0.0.0:901'","Currency":"EUR"}]}}
```

Here my POJO

```
class Root {
@JsonProperty("Init")
var init: Init? = null
}

class MOP {
@JsonProperty("Id")
var id: String? = null

@JsonProperty("Type")
var type: String? = null

@JsonProperty("ProtocolVersion")
var protocolVersion: String? = null

@JsonProperty("MopCode")
var mopCode: String? = null

@JsonProperty("TerminalId")
var terminalId: String? = null

@JsonProperty("IP")
var ip: String? = null

@JsonProperty("Currency")
var currency: String? = null
}

class Init {
@JsonProperty("MOP")
var mop: List<MOP>? = null
 }
```

Here my trial

```
val root: TestClass.Root = gson.fromJson(receiveString,TestClass.Root::class.java)
        val initList = HashMap<String?,String?>()
        if (root.init != null){
            val mopList = root.init!!.mop
            if (mopList != null) {
                for (item in mopList){
                    initList.put(item.mopCode,item.id)
                }
            }

        }
```

Always `root.init` and `root.init.mop` are null

What you can suggest me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json construction has different tree.

You should use following structure:

```
data class Root (
    @SerializedName("Init") val init : Init
)
```

```
data class Init (
    @SerializedName("MOP") val mOP : List<MOP>
)
```

```
data class MOP (
    @SerializedName("Id") val id : Int,
    @SerializedName("Type") val type : Int,
    @SerializedName("ProtocolVersion") val protocolVersion : Double,
    @SerializedName("MopCode") val mopCode : String,
    @SerializedName("TerminalId") val terminalId : String,
    @SerializedName("IP") val iP : String,
    @SerializedName("Currency") val currency : String
)
```

And you can parse just with:

```
Gson().fromJson(data,Root::class.java)
```

Also if you are using Gson, you should use `SerializedName` instead `JsonProperty`.

Comment: @Ibasek how to create this structure? Did you use any web site?

Comment: As a programmer, you should be able to create yourself (its' easy but awful sometimes), but there are some tools to generate that: [json2kotlin.com](https://www.json2kotlin.com/) and AS plugin [JsonToKotlinClass](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-).

Comment: You are right but unfortunately when you fight with time this things can be useful...